# How to add my own dictionary to wordsegment library in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

In order to split words in python I used the wordsegment library which has got inbuilt dictionary based on which the words get splitted. Can someone let me know how to add more words to the dictionary? The code is as follows:

```
import wordsegment as ws
from wordsegment import load, segment
from wordsegment import segment
help(wordsegment)
load()
segment("rollersharp")
['roller', 'sharp']
```

The dictionary is from the link below:
https://github.com/grantjenks/python-wordsegment/tree/master/wordsegment

Answer (score 0):

Usage of custom dictionaries is pretty well covered in [official docs](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/using-a-different-corpus.html).

To extend existing corpus, you need to update `wordsegment.UNIGRAMS` and `wordsegment.BIGRAMS`

Comment: Thanks Slam. I am using unigrams and bigrams but I need to add words which are not present in unigrams.txt and bigrams.txt.Can you suggest me any other method to add new words?

Comment: There's no simple way that I know. Reason for this is that `wordsegment` can not operate only on _words_, it need bigrams to understand where to split the data, and where to not do so. So, you can't get good results by just adding words. You need words + frequency and bigrams + frequency

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a new dictionary follow this link http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/using-a-different-corpus.html . If you want to add words to existing dictionary use

```
import wordsegment as ws
ws.bigram_counts['my text'] = 10.2e6 #basing on number of google search results returned
ws.segment('my text')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome @KousthubhaAK